# What is the purpose of tf.global_variables_initializer?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I would like to understand what `tf.global_variables_initializer` does in a bit more detail.
A [sparse description is given here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/global_variables_initializer):

> Returns an Op that initializes global variables.

But that doesn't really help me. I know that the op is necessary to initialize the graph, but what does that actually mean? Is this the step where the graph is complied?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

A more complete description is given [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/variables).

Only after running `tf.global_variables_initializer()` in a session will your variables hold the values you told them to hold when you declare them (`tf.Variable(tf.zeros(...))`, `tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(...))`,...).

From the TF doc :

> Calling tf.Variable() adds several ops to the graph:
>
> - A variable op that holds the variable value.
> - An initializer op that sets the variable to its initial value. This is actually a tf.assign op.
> - The ops for the initial value, such as the zeros op for the biases variable in the example are also added to the graph.

And also:

> Variable initializers must be run explicitly before other ops in your
>   model can be run. The easiest way to do that is to add an op that runs
>   all the variable initializers, and run that op before using the model.

Comment: Hi, so if you train the weights variables for a neural network, and then you exit the session. Do you need to train them again to run them? does tf.global_variables_initializer() resets the weights to the initial value? how can you save the weights? Thank you.

Comment: You need to set the variables' weights one way or another. You would have to restore your trained weights with a tf.train.Saver in another session. Global_variables_initializer does reset the weights to their initial values.

Answer (score 3):

### In TF1:

---

Using Variables is done in two stages. First we call the `tf.Variable()` function in order to create a Variable and define what value it will be initialized with. We then have to explicitly perform an initialization operation by running the session with the `tf.global_variables_initializer()` method, which allocates the memory for the Variable and sets its initial values.

#### Example:

```
init_val = tf.random_normal((1,5),0,1)
var = tf.Variable(init_val, name='var')
print("pre run: \n{}".format(var))
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    post_var = sess.run(var)
print("\npost run: \n{}".format(post_var))

Out:
pre run:
Tensor("var/read:0", shape=(1, 5), dtype=float32)
post run:
[[ 0.85962135 0.64885855 0.25370994 -0.37380791 0.63552463]]
```

### In TF2:

---

In TF2, variables are initialized immediately when they are created. There is no longer a need to run variable initializers before using them [Doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/global_variables_initializer#expandable-2).